# Please help to identify the language on the photo

Tags: language-identification

The text is on reverse side of photo taken before 1918 at the village Bolhovets (suburbs of Belgorod, south-west Russia).

[image]

I tried so far to find if any language has a letter visually similar to `#` sigh, but could not find any reference. Also, the top line looks like a date, the notation of number `1` and `9` (assuming last 4 symbols are the year) does not help to identify language either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like code (cryptography).

Comment: Agree, I can spot Greek symbols for α, β, γ…there’s a mystery afoot! ‍♀️